# set ForeignKey to be a specific model when posting data

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm fairly new to Django and I have a question.

I have 2 models - Category and Comment. I want the user to be able to post a comment on each category and display them.

When I'm catching the data from the form it asks me to set the category field to some default value - I want the Category model to be saved there so that I can access all comments associated with a particular category. How can I go about this problem?

*I'm not using forms.py, I'm just catching data in the view from html template*

Thank you

**My models**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Comment(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment_body = models.TextField()
    category = ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**My views so far**

```
def category_detail(request, category_id):

    # get the current category
    try:
        current_category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    except Category.DoesNotExit():
        return f"Error - there's not such category"

    context = {
        'current_category': current_category
    }

    # handle POST request
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass
        #username = request.POST['username']
        #comment_body = request.POST['comment']
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Are you getting an error? If so, please add the full error stacktrace, so we can investigate.

Comment: It sounds like you need to pass the Category ID into your template form GET request, so when you POST it, the Category will be passed in with the form.

Comment: Thank you Matt! I will try that